# How to fix "s3_website" issue while pushing Jekyll site on CloudFront through gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, gitlab-ci

I have created Pipeline in GitLabs and I am using docker as gitlab-runner. I want to push Jekyll website on s3 website. And to do so, I am using s3_website gem. I have 4 stages defined in my pipeline. Where I am building Jekyll, creating Artifacts using Gulp, executing test on my jekyll site and then deploying.

All steps are working fine but while doing deployment, I'm getting following error. And i could not figure it how to get this solve.

```
[fail] Could not load the site: Failed to parse ERB in /builds/myproject/s3_website.yml:
       (SyntaxError) /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
           module_function define_method(:warn) {|*messages, uplevel: nil|
```

It is working perfectly fine on my local machine when I'm not on Docker. But when I try to do the same thing using docker. It is giving me above error.

I tried it with ruby 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 on my docker machine. However no luck.

```
bundle exec s3_website push
```

I am expecting this to deploy the site on S3 bucket and corresponding cloudfront.

Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see a syntax error as in https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7608? Can you check if s3_website.yml has proper eol (lf only, not crlf)?

Comment: @vonC Yes, I have seen this thread but it is closed without any specific information. I could not figure out what solution he has found. And s3_website.yml is correct. As i said, i can deploy this through a machine which is not docker instance. It is working fine there. So it means s3_website.yml is correct.

Comment: I get the same error message when trying to push from Travis: https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/480137897/log.txt.  Same command works fine from my computer.

Comment: @kareman can you find some solution. I tried every thing and stuck there from whole week.

Comment: Hi, I'm also having this problem on Codeship since yesterday. Wondering if a minor gem has been upgraded that's breaking all our CIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ran into this same error on CircleCI.  If I understand correctly, the s3_website gem wraps a Java .jar that's using JRuby 1.7, and something must have changed in one of the Docker images or Ruby gems that causes it to start inheriting the system's Ruby 2+ path.  As a result, its JRuby 1.7 tries to load Ruby gems that only work in Ruby 2.0 and above, so it runs into errors.

As a workaround, instead of letting the s3_website gem invoke the .jar file itself, I tell the s3_website gem to only download the .jar file, then I manually invoke it:

```
bundle exec s3_website install
java -cp $(bundle show s3_website)/*.jar s3.website.Push
```

I [reported this](https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/s3_website/issues/323) on the s3_website project's GitHub page.

Comment: Is there a way to turn this command into an alias so I don't have to keep looking up this workaround? I'm afraid this bug is still affecting me to this day :\

Answer (score 0):

Same error message but different solution.

The root of my problem was that the `S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID` wasn't set properly. I source'd my `.env` file

```
source .env
```

And that loaded the access key variable and the deploy worked.